# Use host file on SSH connections

Tags: linux, windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to set up a line on the `hosts` file so that it would be easier to SSH into another computer of mine.

I added the following snippet to it:

```
#Raspberry Pi
192.168.0.8 raspberrypi
```

However, when I do the following command `ssh pi@raspberrypi` the terminal just hangs for a minute, and then returns `ssh: connect to host raspberrypi port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Any help/pointers?

I realized when writing this question that this only happens on Bash for Windows. The line above works well with Git Bash for Windows.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of the `hosts` file have you considered using your `ssh_config` file?  (Assuming the version of `ssh` you're using supports one)

Comment: When I try that, I keep getting a "Bad owner or Permissions" error when trying to do SSH. When I do instead `sudo ssh ...` I get the same error as I got before.

Comment: What are the permissions on your `.ssh` directory and `ssh_config` file? `700` are usually good ones, though I haven't tried this on bash for windows and only really know the permissions on the *nix side of things?

Answer (score 0):

I got "resource temporarily unavailable" when the target system had no SSH Server.
Examination of Windows services showed no SSH Server Broker or SSH Server Proxy. To restore these services, I executed PowerShell command to enable WSL and changed both services to Automatic.